# Django Rest Framework Serializers: Validating object.user is request.user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a REST API with Django Rest Framework and in my ModelViewSet I need to validate that the current `request.user` has the right to edit a particular object.

I have found the part of the documentation that specifies how permissions work– but this is on the ViewSet side, and not the serializer side:

```
class FooViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Foo
    serializer_class = FooSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.foos.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == "list":
            permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
        else:
            permission_classes = [IsObjectUser]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

This will work fine for 403ing when it's not the appropriate user, but I believe I should also be doing serializer-level validation? How can I get the object in question in my `validate` method to check against?

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = [
            "type",
            "title",
            "description",
            "image",
        ]

    def validate(self, attrs):
        # <-- how can I get the object so I can check against the self.request.user?
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is that you shouldn't. Ideally your serializers don't know about the request. That's the views realm (with exceptions). Also, since `user` isn't specified in fields of `FooSerializer` it doesn't make sense to validate the user. If the user could be specified, then it should be validated.

Answer (score 0):

```
   def validate(self, attrs):
        # <-- how can I get the object so I can check against the self.request.user?
         userobj=self.context['request'].user.
         print(attrs)
         title=attrs.get("title")
         enter code here

         attrs.update({'title': title})
         attrs = super().validate(attrs)
         return attrs
```